# Categorical feature with one dominant value

Tags: machine-learning, categorical-data, data-preprocessing

in my dataset for machine learning I have many categorical features with one dominant category as you can see on the picture.
[image]

How can I deal with this kind of categorical data in preprocessing?

Comment: Deal with what?

Comment: In general. I'm not sure if this kind of data should be somehow weighted / transformed or if I can just apply dummy encoding and the fact that one category is dominant will not negatively affect model performance.

Comment: Transformed what for? Why exactly do you need to transform it? What is the problem?

Comment: My problem in general is: Binary classification machine learning scenario (predict 0 or 1). I'm kind of a newbie to the machine learning and I walked through the basic workflow of data preprocessing (dealing with nulls, outliers, encode categorical features as dummy variables and scale features) but even in with my best algorithm the precision is only 0,67 and I need a more precise model. So I was thinking if unbalanced categorical features could negatively affect the precision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking what could be done in terms of preprocessing the data when one of the categories in categorical feature is very frequent. In such case nothing should, or even can, be done. In such case for many samples you observe *the same* value. If you transformed the values in some way, nothing would change about the fact that still many samples have the same category (while it would be encoded using different value). Saying it differently, if you changed the encoding of classes, the only thing that would change is the labels on the $x$-axis of your plot.

What can be done with such features, is you can *create new features* using the categorical variables, this however would be very problem specific and without additional details not much can be recommended. For example, in some cases using [TF-IDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) features may beneficial, or you could replace the categories with the conditional means of the target variable given the category (so called [*mean encoding* or *target encoding*](https://towardsdatascience.com/why-you-should-try-mean-encoding-17057262cd0)), etc. and treat them as continuous features.

Comment: Thank you very much. So this kind of categorical feature will not negatively affect the precision of the model? I can encode them as dummy variables and leave that?

Comment: @soldous This is the data you have. It can either improve the model performance if it is meaningful, or be useless & dropped out of the model, but it is not "wrong". What I'm saying is that this is not something that you need to "correct", but in some cases you could benefit for using this feature differently, by applying more advanced feature engineering techniques.

Comment: ok, thanks again! I'll look at provided techniques